# How to do a OR in a c:if statement in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

How do I properly declare a or statement i try this without success:

<c:forEach var="route" items="${map.street}">
<c:if test="${route.value.type == 'road' || route.value.type == 'street'}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise inclusive OR  --> |

Logical OR --> ||

So...

```
if ( true || false )
{
    /* the first expression is evaluated, it is true, we enter the 'if' block */
}

int i = 1 | 0;  /* i == 1 */
```

Comment: Thats not exactly what i post?

Comment: I'm sorry aparently an enum error, the type road doesnt exist? Your answer was correct

Answer (score 1):

According to http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html the || should work.  When using el, I generally use 'or' instead of '||' but I'm not sure why I do that.